# How to display PayPal Payments Standard option on frontend side in magento 1.7.0.2?

Tags: php, web-applications, paypal, magento-1.7, web-deployment-project

I am using magento 1.7.0.2 and I want to display PayPal Payments Standard option on check out time. everthing is going fine but i am not able to see paypal Standard option checkout time so please help me..i am very try to search my self but it doesnt find so please if u find me this problem..i am very glad to you..thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0):

So take a look at your payment regions. Alot of the time its an issue with the PayPal not being added into the payment region that the customer is in.